# How can I change the command key to be the ctrl key for tmux. It's already mapped for other apps)

Tags: keyboard, mapping

tmux wants me to press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> by default, changed it by having `set -g prefix C-a` in my .tmux_conf file).

I have already switched <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>, so, in general, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will now do <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, etc.

So how can I make tmux also use <kbd>Control</kbd> instead of <kbd>Command</kbd> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you switch `control` and `command` ? Did you use the "Modifier keys" tab from System Preferences > Keyboard ? By doing so, your keys will be switched on all the apps. I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, if no please let me know.